# Coloring the points in a plot based on another numeric variable

Tags: r, colors, plot

I'm plotting "wt" versus "mpg" (from the "mtcars" dataset) and now I want to colour the points based on "hp". 
I want to take the colour Green and to scale its shades, so the high "hp" values would get Dark Green and the low values would get Pale Green.

base plot without colour:

```
data(mtcars)
plot <- with(mtcars, {
  plot(wt, mpg, xlab="Weight", ylab="Miles per Gallon")
})
```

What is the simplest way to do this in R-Base? And what about ggplot2 / lattice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Base R**

You can use `colorRamp` to make a function that returns shades of green:

```
cr <- colorRamp(c("green", "black"))
```

Then you can plot using:

```
with(mtcars, {
    plot(wt, mpg, col = rgb(cr(hp / max(hp)), max=255),
         xlab="Weight", ylab="Miles per Gallon", pch=20)
})
```

`cr` accepts values between 0 and 1, that's why I divide by the `max(hp)`

**ggplot2**

```
p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = wt, y = mpg)) + geom_point(aes(col = hp))
p + scale_colour_gradientn(colours=c("green","black")) + theme_bw()
```

**Plots**

[image]

Hope it helps,

alex

Comment: Thanks, Alex! It's very nice.

Answer (score 0):

Use something like this:

```
library(ggplot2)   
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=wt, y=mpg))+geom_point(aes(col=hp))
```

Change the color to your desired one. maybe [this](http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/scale_brewer.html) or [this](http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/Colors_(ggplot2)/) can help.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the `classInt` package. It provides several methods to transform the numeric variable `hp` into intervals. The package `RColorBrewer` provides sensible palettes. For instance,

```
library(classInt)
library(RColorBrewer)
n <- 5 # number of levels 
hp_ints <- classIntervals(mtcars[, "hp"], n, style="quantile") 
# other options for style include "fixed", "sd", "equal", "pretty", "quantile", "kmeans", "hclust", "bclust", "fisher", or "jenks"
pal <- brewer.pal(n, "Greens")
hp_col <- pal[findInterval(mtcars[, "hp"], hp_ints$brks, all.inside=TRUE)]
plot(mpg~wt, data=mtcars, col=hp_col, pch=19)
```

Comment: For completeness, one could accomplish the same thing with `cut` in base R.